# Are we getting too restrictive here?

Tags: discussion

I was saddened by seeing [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5506/for-deploying-a-public-facing-webapp-debian-lenny-or-debian-squeeze-closed) get closed. Sure it will be outdated in a few years, but so are many questions here. But the fact that there's a date on the question, and the names of the releases (Lenny and Squeeze), means only a careless person will think the info is wholly applicable in 10 years. Also, the question can always be edited with something like "**Outdated! Squeeze is no longer supported**".

If you insist on keeping it closed, where else do you suggest this person should have asked his question instead? Isn't this THE place to ask Unix & Linux questions, far better than mailing lists for simple Q&A?

**UPDATE**: I've updated the question to be more generic, and it has been re-opened.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this question (For deploying a public facing webapp, Debian Lenny, or Debian Squeeze?) is too localized if you interpret it as “Debian stable or testing”.

Even if you read it as “lenny or squeeze”, it might be useful if it was asking whether both versions were *capable* of powering a public-facing webapp. But the answer to that is obviously that both are capable, and the question body requests a *recommendation*.

I've seen bitter arguments about this particular question — people agree on the pros and cons but fight about their respective importance. So I would be tempted to close it as “subjective and argumentative” anyway.

Comment: I want to say I didn't interpret. I read it as it was. It could be reworded to be better, and I wouldn't have closed it.

Answer (score 4):

Consider: can you ask a more generalized version of this question?

It's awfully similar to the problems with the shopping questions:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

In other words, *teach me how to determine the answer myself* -- that is what has lasting value.

Comment: This answer reflects my reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think questions about "Should I use version X or version X+1" are too localized; even "Which version should I use?" is probably useless in the long run. Information that *might* be outdated in a few years is fine; information that will *definitely* be outdated in a few years should probably be closed unless there's some extraordinary reason for keeping it

Comment: Does it matter if the information is useful __today__ even if it will *definitely* be outdated next month?

Comment: @Tshepang Every question is going to be about information useful today, but this is the reason the "too localized" close reason exists